# What does this mean: awk 'OFS="\t" {$1=$1}1' /filepath

Tags: awk

What does following AWK code do:

```
awk 'OFS="\t" {$1=$1}1' /filepath
```

Comment: This is not `awk` proper, either wrap `OFS` in a begin block or define outside of the script with `-v`.

Comment: It should be `awk -v OFS="\t" '{$1=$1}1' /filepath` or `awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" /filepath` or in `BEGIN` block

Comment: @Barmar your edit made my question got negative point

Comment: I doubt my edit had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does this (replace spaces by tabs):

```
OFS="\t" # set output separator as a tab
{$1=$1}  # remove extra spaces and set OFS as tab
1        # with awk, true, so print the current line
```

Comment: The summary is that it converts a whitespace-separated file into a tab-separated file.

Answer (score 2):

It assigns `OFS` to be a tab and then checks if the value of OFS is something other than 0 or null (which it is since you just set it to a tab) and, if so, then it assigns $1 to itself there by causing $0 to be recompiled replacing the FS values with the OFS value. Since FS is the default value of a single blank char that means all leading/trailing white space will be removed and all other chains of contiguous white space will be replaced with a single tab char. It then evaluates the condition `1`, finds it to be true and so executes the default action of printing the current record.

Comment: To support this answer, while it sounds a bit illogic, this is exactly what it does. The first assignment `(OFS="/t")` is placed in a very unusual place. This is why this answer, while seeming weird, is an exact translation what the code does. The normal form.would be `awk -v OFS='/t' '{$1=$1}1'` would have a different explanation.